# Inkscape to trace bitmap with 4k+ colors

Tags: inkscape, svg

I'm trying to convert (trace) this image to an svg file:

[image]

[Full size Image](https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/images/1/13/Provinces.png)

I run Path > Trace Bitmap, 256 colors, no smooth, no stack, remove bg, no optimize paths. It vectorizes ok but the colors are changed slightly, which can't happen, since the rgb of the fill is essentially the ID of the shape, which means I can't map from svg -> the webpage.

It won't let me go over 256 colors either, and there's roughly 4k+. Is there a way around this limit, or is there another program I can also use?

*Edit*: The problem isn't so much the tracing, but the specific colours:

`province  red  green  blue             x       hex
0         1  128     34    64     Stockholm     #802240
1         2    0     36   128  Östergötland     #002480
2         3  128     38   192       Småland     #8026c0`

[image]

On my resulting images, those hex colours don't match to the ones I have on file (and what they are on the original .bmp)

Comment: The image has to be huge for that kind of separation to work out. I gather the file has no AA?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the image is 33mb, not sure what they're thinking with it but it's the only source I have for the info I need

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. Illustrator's image trace can handle many more colours than 256. When I trace it, the result is 5728 colours. [see screenshot here](https://imgur.com/a/n3Fz1)

Comment: I'm having the same thing as Billy Kerr. I would suggest that you consider using illustrator for this project - [my results](https://nofile.io/f/yOvTWsnyJ9u/rsgrw.svg)

Comment: @WELZ - just noticed the OP asked for Inkscape, LOL

Comment: Illustrator is ok too (I have trial) - I added a bit more info. I can trace ok, and it *looks* ok, but the colours are slightly off. In Welz's svg file province 1 is #7F2343, not #802240. Slight difference I know, but it throws the whole thing off unfortunately

Comment: I tried this on Inkscape, and to be honest, you'd be better using Illustrator.  Inkscape's trace works well for some things, but less so for others. The resulting paths are too complex when I try it - even with smoothing on.  For this particular case, Illustrator performs better

Comment: This isn't a practical solution (it'd take hours of manual work) but you can make them all just outlines (with no fill in middle) and place the original behind it, then select each path (using the layers panel) and use the eyedropper tool to select color right under it. (until you finish all ~6800 paths).

Comment: Also just noticed the image file itself is really poor quality - like it was compressed as a jpeg at some point, there are a lot of jpeg artefacts.  Is this the only artwork you have access to?  Inkscape might do better if you started with a better quality image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK the vectorization process in inkscape is just a color quantization + n call to potrace.
I guess the color reduction first stage is done using median-cut algorithm which is prone to color quantization error.

So I think you won't be able to preserve the colors while tracing in inkscape.

Maybe you could try the script @
http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=30972

which is a shell script that uses imagemagick to sort the colors by area in your image and then launch a potrace on a mask for every color then combine the n svgs.

Comment: I do think that may have done the trick - gave me an svg with the correct colours, I have to go through and group up some of them that are related but no biggie - will accept afterwards

Comment: Marking this as accepted, because it did what the question needed, to build an svg while keeping the colours perfect. Thanks